# Transit Visa for Nepalese citizen in Toronto Pearson International

Tags: visas, transit, canada, toronto, nepali-citizens

I am travelling to United States and on my return will be transitting through Toronto Pearson International and transit hours is 3 hours 41 min. Do I need a visa in Toronto Airport? I am a Nepalese Citizen and I hold U.S visitor visa for 5 years.